# variable three.js

Tags: javascript, syntax, three.js

I don't understand exactly what's happening here, it seems that's a syntax issue. Just in case it might be helpful, I'm very new to Javascript, but I have experience with AS3.

On this code:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_lines.html

Line 34 is:

```
camera, scene, renderer;
```

I assumed these were variable declarations on the global scope, and also that in line 42, those were variable declarations as well but on the scope of the init() function.

Line 42:

```
particles, particle;
```

Playing around a little with that code I realized that the script didn't work if I declared the particle object on the global scope like that, but it works if i use it like that:

```
var particle;
```

And also that ir works well if I remove the line 42.

Why does it work like that? What's going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has been formatted poorly (imho). It's not made clear, but:

```
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0,

windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2,
windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2,

SEPARATION = 200,
AMOUNTX = 10,
AMOUNTY = 10,

camera, scene, renderer;
```

This is one single `var` statement, with the commas continuing it over lines. This may answer the confusion and help you rearrange declarations.

Comment: thanks! I'm actually not used to that kind of formatting but I should have noticed it!

Comment: This isn't badly formatted, using a single var statement in this manner is lint.

Comment: @Chad: lint is not the arbiter of style!

Comment: @Len, it is 100% opinion. I would argue that this is *much* more readable than seeing 50 var statements in a row.

Comment: @Chad: oh, I agree with that; the fault I take with it is that the subsequent lines aren't further indented.

Comment: @Len I could agree with that.

Answer (score 0):

Line 42 is indeed

```
particles, particle;
```

however, line 41 contains

var container, separation = 100, amountX = 50, amountY = 50,

so the full statement is (on one line)

```
var container, separation = 100, amountX = 50, amountY = 50, particles, particle;
```

Not to be rude, but it might help to read the code a bit more carefully next time.

Comment: For someone who's new, reading is hard enough without it being formatted badly in the first place.

Comment: I guess, but the lack of blank line immediately drew my eye to the line above.

Comment: @Aatch: indeed (and mine); though, the first block of declarations around line 30 can confuse you enough to stop seeing that.

Comment: Ok, I missed that. I thought you came up with an example, I skipped straight to line 42. So much code for comprehension :hangs head in shame:

Answer (score 0):

'particles, particle' are declared in local scope in line 42 (continuation of line 41). However 'particles' is not used anywhere and 'particle' is used locally. It is always a good practice to declare variable local in javascript . Removing the line 42 makes 'particle' a global variable. However as 'particle' is not required outside the scope of function, it is better to declare it local within the function. 
Javascript is pretty straightforward. You can check references [http://www.w3schools.com/js](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)  &  [http://www.javascriptkit.com](http://www.javascriptkit.com/)